# Weird bug, collectionView view scrolling to second last message, when trying to scroll to bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

using this code to scroll to bottom of collection view. however it scrolls to the second last one only.

```
private func scrollToBottom() {
    let lastSectionIndex = (ChatCollectionView?.numberOfSections())! - 1
    let lastItemIndex = (ChatCollectionView?.numberOfItemsInSection(lastSectionIndex))!-1
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: lastItemIndex, inSection: lastSectionIndex)

    ChatCollectionView!.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: false)
}
```

is anyone familiar with a bug like that

Comment: I use your code, but I get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

Your collection view's frame was under the visible area. You should set its bottom inside visible area.